# development of php oop based project

Tags: php

I want to develop a project which has shopping cart and in this user can design his own product and add that product to shop.And also please send me links of php oops based books which are free of cost.Because im a beginner.

Thanks in advance,
Bhavyasri

Comment: useful for you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3990541/creating-a-fully-functioned-e-commerce-website/3990634#3990634

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is the best PHP Programming Book](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/90924/what-is-the-best-php-programming-book) and [best ecommerce cms](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1900751/best-ecommerce-cms)

Answer (score 0):

Use CMS Zen-cart or  os-commerce and if have good command on oops use magento. These r popular shopping carts of php. Most of ur requirement will be full filled once u install then. that have all of shopping functionality in built.

:)

if still u want to read books I want to suggest

Professional PHP6 (Wrox Programmer to Programmer)  Auther: Steven D Nowicki

Comment: [PHP6 does not exist](http://blog.astrumfutura.com/2009/06/wrox-press-respond-to-the-art-of-deception-or-publishing-php6-books/) and the shop systems are called Magento and osCommerce. What's with that horrid spelling anyway?

Answer (score 0):

OOP is language-agnostic concept. Even in Assembler you can write in OOP-style. You should understand OOP first and then you can easily apply it to any language you use.

I advice "Object-oriented software construction" of B. Meyer.

Answer (score 0):

Personally, I would not spend money or time with books. There are hundreds, even thousands of PHP tutorials to get you started, and once you have the basics, the online PHP manual and stackoverflow should be all you need.

As for eCommerce systems, there are numerous open source PHP systems readily available.

A quick google for 'open source php ecommerce' should give you a start, but off the top of my head, and from my own experience, here's a short list:

- Magento http://www.magentocommerce.com/ - complex but very powerful
- osCommerce http://www.oscommerce.com/ - for your own sanity, and long term prospects, avoid this!
- OpenCart http://www.opencart.com/ - a very good option, can be as complex or simple as you like.
- PHPShop http://code.google.com/p/phpshop/ - simplistic, but easy to get into.

Answer (score 0):

Whatever option you go for (books, web tutorials, etc), one thing you must do is make sure the resource is up-to-date -- PHP's OO code is very different in PHP4 compared with PHP5, and newer versions of PHP5 have improved things further still. The trouble is that there's a *lot* of tutorials and books out there which are out of date and give examples using old-style code.

So make sure you find one that is using the latest version of PHP (currently 5.3).

The last thing you want is to find yourself writing code using PHP4's OO style, because you'll be missing out on all the best features, and you may never even know about it.